# Bootstrap navbar dropdown not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

So I'm trying to get the dropdown in the navbar from Twitter Bootstrap to work, and I'm having some problems.

Here's my html:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active"><%= link_to 'Home', root_path %></li>
  <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">World</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><%= link_to 'Current', current_path %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'All', all_path %></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I also have this in the `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
```

It's just not working, can anyone see anything wrong with it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are referring to a wrong JS file.

Instead of your `<script>` tag you use, use the following:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

`<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

You can read about it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

At the `<ul>` class definition, add the relevant `nav` you wish to use:

`<ul class="nav nav-tabs">`

-----------------------------^^

or 
`<ul class="nav nav-pills">`

You can also directly link to bootstrap-dropdown.js through as per your comment, but nevertheless you'd need bootstrap css and js included (I also updated the fiddle):
`https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js`

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ve97Z/2/)

Also - I see that you use RoR, so make sure it's not a RoR issue on top of the missing JS file.

Comment: okay now that js file isn't 404'ing, which is good.  but its still not working, any other ideas?

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a JSFiddle and I also changed the HTML, please see above

Comment: honestly, i didnt want nav-tabs or nav-pills, and the link i actually needed was for the bootstrap-dropdown.js

Comment: the direct bootstrap dropdown link is https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with bootstrap drop-down(in rails). I resolved the issue by removing the  ***//= require_tree .*** from application.js. And got worked.

Answer (score 0):

Update your jquery main file to 1.11.0 
and only use `bootstrap.min.js bootstrap.min.css and jquery main file`